# rqt gui plugin cpp save and restore settings

Tags: ros, rqt-gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am in the process of writing a plugin for rqt in C++ (yes, I did read the note that highly recommended writing in python) but I have other reasons for writing this in C++.

I'm using the rqt_image_view plugin as a reference. I noticed a couple of functions `saveSettings` and `restoreSettings`. The former saves all current values from the GUI into a `qt_gui_cpp::Settings` object and the latter sets the GUI with values from a `Settings` object.

I am not sure why these particular functions would be called? I tracked it back to the `plugin_bridge.cpp` file in the `qt_gui_cpp`. I'm still not sure as a plugin developer, for rqt, why would I need these functions - what state am I trying to save and restore?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241195/rqt-gui-plugin-cpp-save-and-restore-settings/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written a good amount of rqt tutorials but just realized that there's not much info on these 2 methods.

When you run a GUI, close, and re-open, a lot of times you want to resume the configuration from the last run (e.g. value in the pulldown menu, pane size etc.) In these 2 methods you can specify what components restore the config from the last run (in other words, no config gets restored unless defined in these 2 methods, and the GUI always start with default config).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-09-23**:
What do you mean by "the next run"? Where are the parameters stored in between runs. Does the software close and restart between runs? Thanks

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-09-23**:
[This thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/53721/set-rqt_gui-perspectives-from-command-line/) may help you.